# Creating notes on facebook through FBConnect in iPhone application

Tags: iphone, fbconnect

I have tried FBConnect for iPhone and am able to create/manage sessions and upload pictures successfully. What I can't sort out is, how to create and edit notes.

The Facebook documentation says that notes.create query takes three arguments:title, content and uid. It seems I am unable to form the right request for the required query.

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did [some quick research](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Notes.create) on FBConnect.  There may be more required parameters but to answer your question about generating the right query...

You need to create an NSDictionary to send parameters to Facebook.  So in your case you need something like:

```
    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: aTitle, @"title", aContent, @"content", uid, @"uid"];
```

and then send it off to Facebook with something like:

```
    [[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.Notes.create" params:params];
```

Comment: Thanks Greg. I got the result from your solution. I had some problem with the uid parameter, but I solved it by removing it altogether ;)